# Android: display an image behind the soft keyboard

Tags: android

I would like to create an application that can change / modify your default keyboard so that it has an image behind it (keys would be a little transparent so that you could see the image through the keyboard).

Can you point me in the right direction? I have looked at some sample applications, but this *seems* like an easy task, maybe with an easy solution?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot modify or interfere with the user's default keyboard in any way whatsoever for security reasons.

The only way you'll get this done is if you write your own keyboard.

Comment: Is it possible to sell this keyboard on Market? If yes, then I'm looking for a direction on how to create such a keyboard.

Comment: @duality_ I don't see why not as long as you aren't doing anything questionable with the user's data. As for how to create this keyboard, the SDK has a keyboard sample that you can build upon.